# HTML5 Audio API inputBuffer.getChannelData to audio Array buffer

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api, arraybuffer

I am making an application where I am taking mic data from the inputBuffer and I want to stream to another client and play it. However, I cannot get it wokring.

My recording/capturing works fine so I will skip to relevant parts of the code

```
function recorderProcess(e) {
   var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var convert =  convertFloat32ToInt16(left); 
    window.stream.write(convert);

  var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(lcm);
  playsound(convert);
ss(socket).emit('file',convert, {size: src.size},currentgame);
ss.createBlobReadStream(convert).pipe(window.stream);
//ss.createReadStream(f).pipe(widnow.stream);

}



 function playsound(raw) {
   console.log("now playing a sound, that starts with", new Uint8Array(raw.slice(0, 10)));
    context.decodeAudioData(raw, function (buffer) {
    if (!buffer) {
        console.error("failed to decode:", "buffer null");
        return;
    }
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
    console.log("started...");
   }, function (error) {
      console.error("failed to decode:", error);
   });
   }
```

I am able to successfully create an array buffer using the float32toint16 function, however when I use the init sound function I get an error "null" meaning that the arraybuffer will not decode into an audio stream? Has anyone else had this issue? I have scoured the internet with no answer on how to do this. I am trying to play it this way because ultimately I will be streaming from client to client so I will be sending arraybufers via sockets.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly (there are some missing pieces in your code sample)...

`decodeAudioData` can only decode things like MP3 or WAV. It looks like you're passing it a raw `Int16Array` or `Uint16Array`. Because the underlying `ArrayBuffer` isn't a format that `decodeAudioData` understands, it gives up.

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
function playsound( raw ) {
  // i'll assume you know how to convert in this direction
  // since you have convertFloat32ToInt16
  var buffer = convertInt16ToFloat32( raw ),
    src = context.createBufferSource(),
    audioBuffer = context.createBuffer( 1, buffer.length, context.sampleRate );
  audioBuffer.getChannelData( 0 ).set( buffer );
  src.buffer = audioBuffer;
  src.connect( context.destination );
  src.start( 0 );
}
```

Basically, you already have a way to create the raw `Float32Array` that the Web Audio API likes, so there's no need to decode (and you *can't* decode anyway, since your data isn't a valid file format). So you just convert back to `Float32Array`, create your own `AudioBuffer`, write in the data from `buffer`, and go from there.

Comment: I am going to try it nowe. This is the first round about with Webkit audio and there is barely any documentation on it .

Comment: Oustanding. Now I get the process of webkit audio

Comment: although the process is not completely reversible and I get bad audio loss.

Comment: Hmm. Unless your signal-to-noise ratio is *really* low, 16-bit really shouldn't sound bad. Maybe there's something weird happening in your conversion.

Comment: do you have a link or an example to convert back to 32b float as mine might be wrong?

Comment: Is your array of 16-bit ints signed or unsigned?

Comment: converts to 16 bit unsigned int

Comment: Thanks. 6 years later, this comment solved my issue. :') now I have microphone input in Cordova/Capacitor app.

Answer (score 2):

For converting from float32 to unsigned int 16 you can multiply each float32 value with  0xffff(which is 16 bit max value).  and for int16 to float32 do this reversely which means divide by 0xffff. audio should be fine now.

I am new in stackoverflow. I should write this as a comment but due to lack of reputation point i can't. Thats why i have to write it as a answer. sorry for inconvenience.