# Read ArrayBuffer from a live audio streaming with HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I need to **read the chunks of array bytes** the HTML5 Audio control is receiving form a live stream so then I can **process the array** and generate an audio visualizer.

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="http://some-live-audio-url/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

and a simple Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
    myAudio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
        myAudio.play();
    });
</script>
```

I've tried different options including XMLHttpRequest but that causes CROSS error.

Ideally, I'd need something like:

```
myAudio.addEventListener('SOME EVENT', function(ARRAY) {
    displayVisualizer(ARRAY);
});
```

I will really appreciate any clue or tip you ca give me.

Comment: You might want to check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775704/html5-audio-api-inputbuffer-getchanneldata-to-audio-array-buffer

Comment: Thanks @dvenkatsagar for your answer, I had a quick look and it seems like they got to the point in which they can read the array. var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); I need to know how to get this e.inputBuffer in this case.